# session variable connector not visible in mule palette

Tags: mule, integration, session-variables, mulesoft

**Session Variables**

Session variable connector is not visible in Mule Palette.
When I go to Mule Palette and search for session variable, it doesn't display the connector.
Mule Palette picture:
[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Mule 3 session variables, they do not exist in Mule 4. There is only one type of variables, which are called just vars. They are more or less the same as Mule 3 flow variables.

Note that set any kind of variables, or set payload, are a kind of transformer rather than connectors.

Comment: I wanna retain a variables scope after the flow reference to subflow. I read you can use session variables , so what should be done in mule4?

Comment: You can't use session variables in Mule 4, because they don't exist. Whatever you read it was for Mule 3 only. But even so, variables are not lost in flow to subflow invocation in either version. Have you tried it?

Answer (score -1):

I think you are using Mule4 but In Mule4 we don't have such a type of component.

it is existing in Mule-3 as **In Mule 3**, there are 3 types of variables:

1. Flow Variables
2. Session Variables
3. Record Variables

but in Mule-4 only one type of variable, that we can access by keyword vars.variableName

it is because, in the Mule-4 message structure has been changed
See the below table for a comparison of Mule3 and Mule4 message structure

[image]

Thanks